# push up and swap Navigation Bar in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I've seen this being achieved a few months ago in an app (wish I could remember which).

My main screen is a scrollable view (UITableView) that has the default navigation bar on top, and another added navigation bar at the bottom.
When I scroll down (swipe finger up), the bottom navbar will eventually reach the top. What I'm trying to achieve is to make the top navbar be pushed up by the bottom navbar as I'm scrolling and swap it. All in a smooth transition, which will of course work in the opposite direction (be reversible).

Can anyone give me directions on how to go about doing this?
I have thought about creating an animation, but not sure if its actually possible to push up and out of the screen the "default" navigation bar of the view controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking at is headers for sections in an `UITableView`.

See Apple's documentation on UITableView`: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Specifically, see the `headerViewForSection`method.

Comment: sorry for the late accept, did not have a chance to test it until now. Thank you.